# Why are my swfs not the right resolution?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, size

Forgive me if this is a really stupid question, but I cant figure it out.

I must admit this is my first project in flex as opposed to flash cs3.

All of the assets that I'm using in my .swc are in a .fla that is 1024x768.

Nothing in my actionscript code is scaling down the size of my app, but every time I test my project, my project only takes up maybe 600x500 of the stage, instead of filling it up as I had imagined..

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you running in standalone flashplayer or in browser?

Comment: In standalone player. In the browser, it fills the screen, which is right, but the same thing doesn't happen when I run the swf directly.

Answer (score 0):

In standalone player use exact width and height not percentage.

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" width="1024" height="768">
    <!-- more staff -->
</mx:Application>
```

And as far as I know there are no way to may it work in standalone player with percentage.